# refresh current url onchange event handler

Tags: javascript

how to refresh the the current URL onchnage of the drop down box value,i tried the following but there seems to be an error

```
        <select id='account-select-box' onchange='window.location ='+document.URL+';'>
            <option selected>Link 1</option>
            <option >Link 2</option>
            <option >Link 3</option>
        </select>
```

Error is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: why  not  `window.location.href`

Try this instead if you want to redirect on some other page.

Comment: ne need to use.href, location is ok

Comment: What's wrong with `onchange="location.reload()"`?

Answer (score 2):

You have too much going on

**1.** Fixing your original code

```
<select id='account-select-box' onchange="window.location=document.URL">
```

**2.** improving your code

```
 <select id='account-select-box' onchange="location.reload(1)">
```

**3.** Asking oneself why? what are you trying to achieve? What is the point of reloading when you change the select?

Do you mean

```
<select id="account-select-box" 
onchange="var loc = this.value; if (loc) location=loc">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="http://google.com">Google</option>
  <option value="http://mdn.com">MDN</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But on refresh if i had choosen link 2 then the option would get reset to link 1 again right?

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? What is the user supposed to see when he changes the dropdown

Comment: it is suppose to get all the values pertaining to link 2,bu then this is the index.html page and so it resets the drop down value too

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. What is supposed to get what values pertaining to link 2 from where and then why do you reload?

Comment: What did you get? I am still confused